# What minifig configuration has been included in the most sets?

Tags: minifigures, history

Which minifigure configuration has been included in the most sets? I'm looking for the color of the head, arms, hands, legs, pelvis, and torso as well as the facial expression and any headgear. Please include an image of this minifigure doppleganger.

Comment: hmm, tricky one. Obviously the combination of yellow head and hands, probably (just) the original minifig face, but beyond that it gets a bit more ambiguous...

Comment: Presumably you would consider a printed torso or legs to be different from an unprinted on in the same base colour? Preliminary research shows that once again Black Torsos are just in the lead (165 in 124 sets) above White Torsos (162 in 104 sets) and Red (146 in 97), but it's the combinations of arms and legs that throw it... Lots of Knights though and quite a few police and firemen...

Comment: :) Yes. Painted details count as a different piece. I'm looking forward to your answer!

Comment: There should be some way to get this from bricklink or peeron. I bet on a red torso

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far, the best I can think of is the [red classic space guy](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=sp005) which appeared in 46 sets.

Considering minifigs were less specialized back then, I bet the winner is in that time period anyway, and the fact that spacemen wore an uniform makes me think there is no other minifig apperaing in 46 sets. Even the basic [city worker](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=but011) only reaches a pale 21 sets.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking either Space or Knights - the Classic Castle came with 8 blue knights for example, with breastplates and helms for decoration...

Comment: Which begs the question, should we count a set with multiple instance of the same minifig as one? (Not to mention some of the space sets are actual duplicates for different markets)

Comment: Hmm, good question - the Blue Knight configuration might have appeared the most times due to being in there 8 times, but he was only in 1 or 2 sets...

Answer (score 6):

The [Skeleton with Basic Skull](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=gen001) appears in 42 sets. If you include the sets that have the same figure only with different headgear, the number of sets is 56.

Answer (score 1):

If you had one of every set in [peeron](http://peeron.com/)'s database:

Torso: [973](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/973) - A plain torso - Black

Head: [3626ap01](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/3626ap01) - Normal plain smile - Yellow

Legs: [970c00](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/970c00) - Plain legs - Black

Their database is not complete, I haven't been able to find data for colour of hands or arms, and this is for each peice individually, not the minifigure as a whole, but I think it's the best that can be done.

This image isn't very good quality, but I had a go in Photoshop...

[image: the image]